# Confusion matrix predicted labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, scikit-plot

I am using the following piece of python code to generate a normalized confusion matrix

```
import scikitplot as skplt 
skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, normalize=True)
```

and this gives me the plot as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIQeq.png). However, I wanted to rotate the texs on the x-axis (the predicted values, i.e., neutral, happy, sad). Instead of in a horizontal line, I want the predicted values on the x-axis to be rotated (as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpwaa.png)) and keep the true labels as they are (horizontal).How can we do this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use scikitplot, I believe there is `x_tick_rotation` argument in the `plot_confusion_matrix` [function](https://scikit-plot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metrics.html). So you could rotate xticks to 45 degrees as follows.

```
skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, x_tick_rotation=45, normalize=True)
```

Comment: This is completely for a different task, sir. Please give an answer according to the simple piece of code I included. This is more confusing

Comment: I have updated the answer if you want to use scikit-plot. Please see if this works

Comment: AWESOME! That's exactly what I was looking for and thank you. I mark your answer as  ACCEPTED!

Comment: By the way, the plot adds a "Normalized Confusion Matrix" text on its top. Is there any way to turn this text off?

Comment: You can try setting `title` argument to a space (' '). `skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, title=' ', x_tick_rotation=45, normalize=True)`

Comment: It's better to update your answer accordingly; posting code snippets in the comments should be avoided